# How do we ask about two couples?

Tags: grammar

Let's assume we have two men and two women. They seem like couples.

Can I ask this question?

Are you guys couples? (Are you four couples?)

Or is it grammatically incorrect? And I can only say:

Are you guys a couple?

Comment: *Are you guys couples? (Are you **two** couples?).* A "couple" is already **2** - if there were ***four*** couples, that would be ***eight*** people.

Comment: "Are you guys couples?" seems OK. I don't see a grammar problem, anyway.

Answer (score -1):

"Are you guys a couple" ( When addressing only two people)

"Are you guys couples"  (when asking more than two people)

I wouldn't go ahead with this, as it may confuse people. How would they know that you're asking them all?

Seems syntactically invalid and abnormal.

Answer (score -3):

"Are you guys' couples" works. It implies that there are two couples no matter who is with whom.

Comment: *Guys'* with an apostrophe doesn't work in writing: it changes the meaning of the sentence completely. It does work in speech because you can't see a spoken apostrophe.

Comment: *Guys'* with an apostrophe doesn't work here because it's ***meaningless / syntactically invalid***.